# What does # mean in Windows Explorer column?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, sorting, column

What does `#` mean in the Windows Explorer column?

[image: Column selection dialog]

I've never seen something written in that column.

Comment: # is what the US uses for 'number'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means *Track number*

> In the catagories [sic] where you will find things like "artist"and "alblum" [sic], there is a small column with a "#" (pound sign) in it.  Click it once to arange [sic] the music by track number if that data is apart of the music files information, click it again to reverse the order in which it numericaly [sic] arranges the tracks.
>
> [How to arrange music files by track number, not alphabetically](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/how-to-arrange-music-files-by-track-number-not/cbfb0db6-82e3-441c-a82a-556cc04bf5b8)

> The property name for track number is track: or simply the # symbol:
>
> > `kind:music AND #:=[]` returns music files with no track entries. `kind:music AND track:=[]` same results as above.
>
> [Using Windows Explorer to Query Music Files](https://community.mp3tag.de/t/using-windows-explorer-to-query-music-files/19210)

Open any music folder in Windows and you'll see that column shown by default. If you rip any audio CDs into files you'll see that column being filled with the track number from the CD. Same thing when you buy the whole album from some app

[image: Music view in Explorer]